# Linux - Debian - Original groups that a user is in

Tags: linux, debian, user-accounts, linux-mint, sudo

This is embarrassing; I used the **usermod** command to add myself to the disk group. However I forgot to use the append option! so I'm not a member of any of the groups that I was originally, now terminal says that I'm not even a **sudoer** (How rude!). So the question is: **What are the original groups that a normal Administrator type of user is in**? BTW, I am using Linux Mint Debian Edition (**LMDE**).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have by default in sid:

```
ice@distantstar:~ ➜ groups
ice cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev scanner bluetooth netdev
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have not made other changes, /etc/group- should have have your old settings.

Comment: But group- only shows the list of groups not their members, am I right?

Comment: It should show members. Your primary group should be in /etc/passwd- also. These should all be backup copies, but are overwritten if you makes another change. System files or settings should never be changed without first backing up.